# Any reason I shoudn't add GUID validation to my Visual C++ program?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, error-handling, guid

In order to make my Visual C++ program more robust I'm tempted to insert checks that `GUID` variables [contain valid version 4 GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1771410/57428) (and are not left uninitialized):

```
GUID guid;
UuidCreate( &guid );
// many lines of code later...
// the following assert should not fire for valid version 4 GUIDs
int data3 = guid.Data3;
assert( ( data3 >> 12 ) == 4 );
```

I'm completely sure that all GUIDs will either normally come from within `UuidCreate()` function or be uninitialized variables (and the latter is what I'd like to diagnose with those checks). My only concern is Microsoft could suddenly change GUID implementation in future versions of Windows.

What other factors should I consider to decide whether such checks won't hurt? Also how likely is it that GUID implementation changes on future versions of Windows?

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to validate GUIDs from UuidCreate?

Comment: @KristoferA - Huagati.com: That's for illustration only, the real problem is an uninitialized GUID might be passed and that would indicate a design fault in my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My only concern is Microsoft could suddenly change GUID implementation in future versions of Windows.

Deal with it, if it happens. No, seriously, you could also worry about the implementation of `integer`, Microsoft could decide to switch to the .NET datatypes and make the `integer` system-wide a 4-byte value.

Worry about other things, if implementations are changing, you'll have to rewrite/change/fix your program anyway.

**Edit:** If I understand you right, you're worrying about the *return* value of the function, not the GUID-Structure itself. And you mean that at the moment it can return either a GUID or the uninitialized value, but in future implementations it might return a 0-filled-GUID?

In that case I stick to my first paragraph, worry about it if it happens. At the moment the function has a clearly defined behavior, work with that. Check for uninitialized values and that's it. You can't guess what Microsoft will do in the future (hell, sometimes even Microsoft can't).

Comment: Agree with Bobby. Worrying about some obscure and ever changing API can be reasonable, but worrying if a base type will be changed somewhere in the future is quite useless.

Comment: @kappa: The GUID structure itself is not a concern for me - the algorithm that constructs values is the concern.

Comment: @sharptooth: I've edited my answer, I hope I understood you right.

Comment: @sharptooth, Since asserts only affect debug builds I'd say it's not worth worrying about. If, one day, those asserts all start firing then they can always be removed or updated to handle the new format. The important thing is to do the asserts inside a well-named inline function, so that a) It's obvious what they are testing and b) You only have to update one thing if you need to update/remove the assert in the future.

Comment: Well, if you worry about Microsoft changing the `UuidCreate` implementation seems to me a little too much: that function should always return a valid GUID, does it really matter if it's version 4, 5, 6 or 8723? If what concerns you is simply if the function returns no value, initialize the variable before calling the function to something known - let's say, all zeros - and check after the function if the value is still all zeroes.

Comment: @kappa: If I insert those check and Microsoft changes the implementation so that there's say 7 or just any value where I expect 4 those checks will fail even if there's no actual problem and I'll have to edit and reship my program.

Comment: @sharptooth: Why not just do these asserts in debug builds, then? If you can't be 100% an assert is valid then it doesn't belong in a release build but it can still be useful to catch errors during development.

Comment: I added validation only to builds that aren't shipped to the user. I guess it'll be the best solution - won't break anything.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's see... you're calling UuidCreate without being able to specify a particular GUID version, and you're going to expect a particular version in return? How is that a good idea?

If you're trying to make your software "more robust", how about initializing your variables and checking for errors?

```
GUID guid = {0};
if (SUCCEEDED(UuidCreate( &guid ) ) {
    // you can be _pretty_ sure guid has some valid stuff in it
}
```

Comment: Okay, but what if some of such initializers are somehow bypassed because of erroneous code? I'd like to catch obviously invalid GUID values later.