# How to validate GUID is a GUID

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, guid

How to determine if a string contains a GUID vs just a string of numbers.

will a GUID always contain at least 1 alpha character?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to distinguish a GUID from just a random number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771410/is-there-a-way-to-distinguish-a-guid-from-just-a-random-number)

Answer (score 277, accepted):

See if these helps :-

1. `Guid.Parse` - [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Guid_Parse_System_String_)

```cs
Guid guidResult = Guid.Parse(inputString)
```

2. `Guid.TryParse` - [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparse#System_Guid_TryParse_System_String_System_Guid__)

```cs
bool isValid = Guid.TryParse(inputString, out guidOutput)
```

Comment: .NET 4.0 : Second link...else, first link. +1

Comment: C# 7.0 use var or Guid or _ for inline out variables `bool isValid = Guid.TryParse(inputString, out var tempGuid);` or `bool isValid = Guid.TryParse(inputString, out _);`

Answer (score 28):

This is a fairly clean, modern C# approach that suppresses the out variable:

```
var isValid = Guid.TryParse(inputString, out _);
```

Answer (score 17):

When I'm just testing a string to see if it is a GUID, I don't really want to create a Guid object that I don't need.  So...

```
public static class GuidEx
{
    public static bool IsGuid(string value)
    {
        Guid x;
        return Guid.TryParse(value, out x);
    }
}
```

And here's how you use it:

```
string testMe = "not a guid";
if (GuidEx.IsGuid(testMe))
{
...
}
```

Comment: update for 2018 `return Guid.TryParse(value, out var _);`

Answer (score 9):

A GUID is a 16-byte (128-bit) number, typically represented by a 32-character hexadecimal string.  A GUID (in hex form) need not contain any alpha characters, though by chance it probably would.  If you are targeting a GUID in hex form, you can check that the string is 32-characters long (after stripping dashes and curly brackets) and has only letters A-F and numbers.

There is certain style of presenting GUIDs (dash-placement) and regular expressions can be used to check for this, e.g.,

```
@"^(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})$"
```

from http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view8AD536EF-BC0D-427F-9F15-3A1BC663848E.htm.  That said, it should be emphasized that the GUID really is a 128-bit number and could be represented in a number of different ways.

Answer (score 6):

There is no guarantee that a GUID contains alpha characters. `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF` is a valid GUID so is `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` and anything in between.

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can use the answer above for the Guid.Parse and Guid.TryParse. Otherwise, you can do something like this:

```
public static bool TryParseGuid(string guidString, out Guid guid)
{
    if (guidString == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("guidString");
    try
    {
        guid = new Guid(guidString);
        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        guid = default(Guid);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Will return the Guid if it is valid Guid, else it will return Guid.Empty

```
if (!Guid.TryParse(yourGuidString, out yourGuid)){
          yourGuid= Guid.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(MyGuid != Guid.Empty) 
{
   // Valid Guid
} 
else
{
   // Invalid Guid
}
```

Comment: This just checks if a given Guid is equal to an Guid.Empty. It doesn't check if a given string is a valid Guid

Answer (score 1):

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

There is no guarantee that an alpha will actually be there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer I created an Extension method as follows:

```
public static Guid ToGuid(this string aString)
{
    Guid newGuid;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aString))
    {
        return MagicNumbers.defaultGuid;
    }

    if (Guid.TryParse(aString, out newGuid))
    {
        return newGuid;
    }

    return MagicNumbers.defaultGuid;
}
```

Where "MagicNumbers.defaultGuid" is just "an empty" all zero Guid "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000".

In my case returning that value as the result of an invalid ToGuid conversion was not a problem.

Comment: Why use MagicNumbers over Guid.Empty?

Comment: In my opinion, this is the kind of roll-your-own answer that just completely ignores any and all tools the framework is already giving you.

Answer (score 0):

Use GUID constructor standard functionality

```
Public Function IsValid(pString As String) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim mGuid As New Guid(pString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True

End Function
```

Comment: Be aware that the question was made for C# language and the provided answer is in VB.Net. Would be nice to map it for C#.