# Guid string should only contain hexadecimal characters

Tags: c#, guid

What is wrong exactly with this Guid? I get the error in the subject.

531fe55b-9qa5-4be3-af52-112e5adqe7a7

I am very sure that it was generated through .NET from the beginning.

Comment: What are you doing to get this error?

Comment: `9qa5` - I'm fairly sure that `q` isn't a valid hex character, those being `0123456789abcdef`. There's a second `q` later on also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A guid should not contain any q

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that it contains the letter `q`.

```
531fe55b-9qa5-4be3-af52-112e5adqe7a7
          ^                    ^
```

This is not a valid [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) character.

Comment: Thank you all. I was so puzzled over the error because I could bet my hat it was generated my .NET.

Answer (score 2):

From a quick trawl (about validating a Guid):

[How to validate GUID is a GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211017/how-to-validate-guid-is-a-guid)

Basically, you can only have hex characters in a Guid, so the 'q's in your GUID above are not valid.

I sincerely doubt that this originally came from the framework.