# Checking if input is GUID or not

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on this little project and what I have to do is to check if the user input is GUID or not.

I have created this Stored Procedure on SQL and it works pretty fine.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[oid_validation] @oid varchar(max)
as
BEGIN TRY

if  (TRY_CAST(@oid as uniqueidentifier) IS NOT NULL)
begin
 (select select * From Student where oid=@oid)
end
else begin
select 'KO'
end 

end TRY
Begin CATCH
print('error')
end CATCH
```

On my ASP.NET MVC app on the other hand, I want to show the data that this procedure returns, based on whether the input was GUID or not.
So my View is:

```
 @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
            {
              
                    <div class="ct1">
                        <h4>Oid: </h4>
                        <h4>Name: </h4>
                        <h4>Lastname: </h4>
                        <h4>Study_Year: </h4>
                        <h4>Birthday: </h4>
                        <h4>City:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ct2">
                        <h4>@row["oid"]</h4>
                        <h4>@row["Name"]</h4>
                        <h4>@row["Lastname"]</h4>
                        <h4>@row["StudyYear"]</h4>
                        <h4>@row["Birthday"]</h4>
                        <h4>@row["City"]</h4>
                    </div>
                }
```

This also works fine. By this the users will see the data they wanted, again **based on whether that input was guid or not*.
Now what I'm trying to do is manipulate something so if the user enters invalid input, to show some text or redirect somewhere else;

Something like this:

```
if(userinput!=guid)
{
<h4>Your data is invalid, please check your string!</h4>
}
else
{
//foreach(...)
{
<data1>

@<data1>
}
}
```

Comment: [`Guid.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparse) or [`Guid.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparseexact)?

Comment: What actually is your question? What are you stuck on?

Comment: Hi, I am stuck on that if(userinput is not Guid) { show something} else { read the data}.

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6211017/107625)?

Comment: Doesn't seem that SQL Server is involved in the part you need help with?

Comment: @DaleK, not really, my stored procedure works fine, at least I think so...as far as it gives the users the data they search for...yes.
But I want to handle it when the stored procedure fails. If the user inputs invalid data, then redirect them somewhere else or at least show a message.

Comment: If `@oid` is meant to contain a `uniqueidentifier` why do you define it as a 2 billion character string?

Comment: @larnu because I was testing at first and was not much informed about GUID's and how much characters it will take. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use Regex to check the input:

```
//returns true
Regex.IsMatch(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"(?im)^[{(]?[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}[)}]?$")
```

or use the built in function like suggested:

```
Guid g;

if (Guid.TryParse(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), out g))
{
    return "Success";
}
```

Comment: Why not use the built-in [`Guid.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparse) or [`Guid.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparseexact)?

Comment: This actually worked. I have been search everywhere for this answer. Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are doing your input validation at the wrong level. Your stored procedure should take in a unique identifier and you should be validating the input to your ASP.NET MVC endpoint before doing anything with it.

e.g.

```
ActionResult SearchStudents(SearchParams searchParams) {
     if (!ModelState.IsValid) ... handle validation errors

     ... Call your stored procedure once valid
}

class SearchParams {
    [Required]
    Guid StudentId { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but It returns an error to my View saying that : **Column 'oid' does not belong to table**

Comment: This would suggest that your student table doesn't have an oid column.  You should try running the sproc directly.

Comment: Yes you're right. But the sproc has *oid* as parameter and that's where things were kind of messy because I had to show the user some data based on his input, which is related with the parameter of sproc. If the userinput/parameter is right, sproc gets executed and the user will get their data, if not...**blank**. Hella messy,right ? haha. But I got it to work thanks to you guys. I appreciate your time and help.